# How to get hybrid Map View in Android?

Tags: android, dictionary

How can I set map View to hybrid?
Please Help

Comment: What do you mean by hybrid map!? Satellite and street view?

Comment: @Adinia Satellite and street view both together

Comment: mapView.setSatellite(true);
mapView.setStreetView(true);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default mapView shows standard map, when you add:
 `mapView.setSatellite(true);`

you get the hybrid view of standard map and satellite map, making setSatellite false will again only display standard map. Hope this answers the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs about [MapView](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html).

More specifically:

- setSatellite()
- setStreetView()